# How to pass current path's directories names (with spaces) as arguments to a bash script?

Tags: bash, perl

I can reproduce this problem on both ubuntu bash and windows/cygwin bash.
The problem happens with file and directory names that have spaces in them.
Here is my script called pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh:

```
for dir in "$@"
do
  echo dir = $dir
done
```

This works great:

```
./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh *
dir = pass-file-names-with-spaces.sh
dir = this is a directory with spaces in it
dir = this is a file name with spaces.txt
dir = this is another file name with spaces.txt
```

I get the full file name on each line, even when it has spaces in it. Sometimes this is perfectly acceptable because I want file names and directory names. However, sometimes I want to implement a filter with perl to remove the file names.

The backtick/perl approach is not working! Here is my first attempt to escape the spaces.

```
./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh `perl -e ' my @m  = (); my $c = shift @ARGV; opendir $h, $c or die "cannot opendir $c"; @a= map { push @m, $_ if  -d $_ } grep(!/^\.\.$/,readdir $h); closedir $h; foreach (@m){s/ /\\\\ /g; print " $_ " } '  .`
dir = .
dir = this\
dir = is\
dir = a\
dir = directory\
dir = with\
dir = spaces\
dir = in\
dir = it
```

I tried using quotes instead:

```
./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh `perl -e ' my @m  = (); my $c = shift @ARGV; opendir $h, $c or die "cannot opendir $c"; @a= map { push @m, $_ if  -d $_ } grep(!/^\.\.$/,readdir $h); closedir $h; foreach (@m){ print " \"$_\" " } '  .`
dir = "."
dir = "this
dir = is
dir = a
dir = directory
dir = with
dir = spaces
dir = in
dir = it"
```

It seems that bash is ignoring my quotes! It seems that the "$@" is misbehaving! How can I filter out the file names?

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: do you know about `find -type d` ? Good luck.

Comment: [Don't use backticks in shell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the way you pass directory names which is not right.

You need to re-structure the call like this (simplified version of perl script):

```
readarray -t -d '' dirs < <(perl -e 'print "$_\x00"')
./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh "${dirs[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

- `set --`: Empty the arguments array.
- `for d in *; do`: Iterate each directory entry as variable `d`.
- `[ -d "$d" ] && set -- "$@" "$d"`: If entry `d` is a directory, add it to the arguments array.
- `./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh "$@"`: Finally pass the arguments array to your script or command.

```sh
set --
for d in *; do
  [ -d "$d" ] && set -- "$@" "$d"
done
./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh "$@"
```

Now, to reflect [@Shellter's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413259/how-to-use-the-bash-backtick-to-filter-arguments-with-spaces-to-bash-script/61414182#comment108641575_61413259), lets use `find`:

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec ./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh {} +
```

Or if `find` is too old for the `-exec command {} +` syntax:

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\0' |
  xargs -0 ./pass-dir-names-with-spaces.sh
```